# A convergence problem about integral operator in the space of representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, fa.functional-analysis

This would be a basic problem in representation theory.

Let $G$ be a unimodular real Lie group, $(\pi,V)$ a smooth representation of $G$ in a Frechet space $V$. Let $f$ be a smooth function on $G$. Now define the operator $\pi(f)$ as $$\pi(f)v=\int_G f(g)\pi(g)vdg$$
for any $v\in V$.

Now the question is that in order to show $\pi(f)$ is an operator on $V$, i.e. $\pi(f)v\in V$ for any $v$, it suffices to check $$|\pi(f)v|_{\mu}<\infty$$

for some particular seminorm $||_{\mu}$, or to check that is finite for ALL seminorms on $V$ ?

In particular, if $(\pi,V)$ is the smooth vectors in a unitary representation, then for all smooth function $f$, which is also in $L^1(G)$,  $\pi(f)$ is an operator on $V$, and in fact continuous,right?

Many thanks.

Comment: There are two things. First you need to show that the integral for $\pi(f)v$ converges, usually in the weak sense (i.e. $\int_G f(g)h(\pi(g)v)dg$ exists in $\mathbb{C}$ for every $h\in V'$, the topological dual of $V$). Then you need to show that $\pi(f)$ is continuous as an operator $V\rightarrow V$, i.e. for every seminorm $\mu$ on $V$, there is a constant $C>0$ and seminorms $\nu_1,...,\nu_k$ such that $|\pi(f)v|_\mu \leq C.\max_{1\leq i\leq k} |v|_{\nu_i}$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Here I'm more interested in if $\pi(f)$ converges to certain vector in $V$. Do we need the continuity prior to this question?

Comment: I extended my response to include more general $f$'s. I don't think the integral makes sense for every $f\in L^1(G)$, one needs some "decay at infinity", see below.

Comment: @unknown: I don't understand what you mean by "$\pi(f)$ converges to certain vector in $V$", as this mixes objects of different nature. Now remember that we can always add the zero seminorm to the family of seminorms defining the topology of $V$. For this one, the condition $|\pi(f)v|_\mu <\infty$ is trivial, so you can get no satisfaction with just one seminorm.

Comment: Alain: Thanks for your comment. It should be $\pi(f)v$ converges to a vector in V for any $v\in V$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Alain: Of course we can always add zero seminorm. And the question I asked is that among all the seminors there, trivial or nontrivial, can we just pick up one particular one , and check the condition for it, then conclude that $\pi(f)v$ exists in $V$? Or we need to check the condition for all seminorms?

Comment: @unknown: I think if you want $\pi(f)$ act on the set of smooth vectors in a unitary representation (i.e. $\pi(f)v$ not only exists in $V$ but it is also a smooth vector), then you need that $L_X f\in L^1(G)$ for any $X\in\mathfrak{g}$. This is because for $f\in C_c^\infty(G)$ we have that $\pi(X)\pi(f)v=\pi(L_X f)v$. 

Answer (score 1):

I would think the answer is yes and follows by applying "[1.0.1] Theorem" on page 2 [here](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/Notes/07_vv_integrals.pdf) for the finite Borel measures $\Re^+f(g)dg$, $\Re^-f(g)dg$, $\Im^+f(g)dg$, $\Im^-f(g)dg$ on $G$, where $\pm$ stands for positive and negative part. Note that Frechet spaces satisfy the conditions there.

**EDIT.** As the OP pointed out, the result is stated for compactly supported functions. By an approximation argument and the last line of the quoted theorem, an extension seems possible to functions $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $\int_G |f(g)|\ |\pi(g)v|_\mu\ dg < \infty$  for each seminorm $|\cdot|_\mu$ that participates in the definition of the topology of $V$.

Comment: Thanks. But it seems in that theorem it requires f to be compactly-supported... 

Comment: Thanks a lot. So it looks like the question for the particular case when $\pi$ is from a unitary representation I asked is fine.
